# How can I add an extra level to a curried function?

Tags: javascript, function, currying

Instead of:

```js
const fn = (ctx, a, ...rest) => {};
const fnCurried = (ctx) => (b) => (...rest) => fn(ctx, b, ...rest);

someFn("something", fnCurried(ctx));
```

I would like to be able to call "fn" at top level, so I thought maybe storing the context in another method would help, I have no idea how to go about doing this

```js
const fnCurried = createCtx(ctx)
someFn("something", fnCurried(fn))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, `someFn` takes a second argument as a function of the form:

```
(b) => (...rest) => fn(ctx, b, ...rest);
```

In your second example, you want to keep this behaviour, this means calling `fnCurried(fn)` must return the above function. We can do this by writing:

```
const fnCurried = (fn) => (b) => (...rest) => fn(ctx, b, ...rest);
```

However, if we just use this, then we haven't supplied the context anywhere. That's where we can make another function called `createCtx()` that will return the above fnCurried function for us, while also closing over a supplied `ctx`:

```
const createCtx = ctx => fn => b => (...rest) => fn(ctx, b, ...rest);
const fnCurried = createCtx(ctx);
someFn("something", fnCurried(fn));
```

The `createCtx` function allows us to pass in the context, which then returns `fnCurried` for us, that can be passed into `someFn` once called